# Como puedo desahabilitar una llave foranea en una tabla para hacer un truncate en slq server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

quiero saber si hay una forma de como desahabilitar una llave foranea, para poder eliminar los registros de una tabla, pero cuando hago utilizo este script: alter table dbo.AMBITO NOCHECK constraint ALL --Desactivar, me sigue sin poder eliminar los registros de una tabla, lo necesito hacer sin un procedimiento almacenado

Comment: puedes probar quitando los datos de la tabla a la cual hace referencia la foranea y luego ejecutas el truncate a la tabla que necesitas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

puedes probar quitando los datos de la tabla a la cual hace referencia la foranea y luego ejecutas el truncate a la tabla que necesitas

Comment: Hola Kevin, por favor edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle porque, aunque puede servir de guía para solucionar el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Trata de añadir una explicación más detallada y, a ser posible, algo de código para mostrar cómo se haría. Lee [answer] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Para desactivar una restricción de llave foránea puedes utilizar:

```
ALTER TABLE nombreTabla NOCHECK CONSTRAINT nombreRestriccion;
```

Por ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE estudiante NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_estudiante_carrera;
```

El el anterior ejemplo se está deshabilitando la restricción de la llave foránea carrera en la tabla estudiante. Lo anterior funcionaría si al momento de haber creado la tabla se tuviera algo como lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE estudiante(
--Campos de la tabla
carrera INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_estudiante_carrera FOREIGN KEY (carrera) 
REFERENCES carrera (id)
);
```

Es decir, los anteriores ejemplos servirían si desde el momento que tu creaste tu tabla le asignaste un nombre a la restricción de llave foránea que estabas creando.

```
--Para volver a activar la restricción
ALTER TABLE estudiante CHECK CONSTRAINT fk_estudiante_carrera;
```

Sin embargo también es posible deshabilitar todas las restricciones que hay en las tablas usando el procedimiento almacenado *sp_msforeachtable*:

```
-- Para desactivar todas las restricciones

EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";


-- Para volver a activar todas las restriciones
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";
```

Por ultimo, te dejo una información que a lo mejor podría serte útil; si deseas eliminar todos los datos de una tabla debes tener en cuenta que puedes usar TRUNCATE o DELETE considerando lo siguiente:

```
-- DELETE se ejecuta aunque la tabla se relacione con otras tablas siempre y cuando no existan registros asociados. Para ellos primero se eliminan los registros asociados. Para ello primero se eliminan los registros asociados y después se puede vaciar la tabla.

DELETE FROM nombreTabla;

-- TRUNCATE no se puede ejecutar si la se tabla relaciona con otras tablas aunque no haya registros, se puede solucionar cambiando la restricción de llaves foráneas de las tablas involucradas por ON DELETE CASCADE y ON UPDATE CASCADE. Solo así se permite vaciar la tablas (también se eliminarían todos los registros que se relacionen con la tabla que se trunco).

TRUNCATE TABLE nombreTabla;
```